# How do i make Application Insights Rest Api return all data even if it doesn't exist?

Tags: rest, azure, azure-application-insights

So I'm trying to get the number of browser exceptions in the last day every hour using the GET request using the demo credentials:

```
https://api.applicationinsights.io/beta/apps/DEMO_APP/metrics/exceptions/browser?timespan=P1D&interval=PT1H
```

but it doesn't return all the data, it only returns the data that has been set as shown:

```
{ 
  start: '2017-08-22T13:00:00.000Z',
  end: '2017-08-22T14:00:00.000Z',
  'exceptions/browser': { sum: 1 } 
}
{ 
  start: '2017-08-23T04:00:00.000Z',
  end: '2017-08-23T05:00:00.000Z',
  'exceptions/browser': { sum: 1 } 
}
```

how do i make it so it returns every single bit of data even if the sum is 0? for example:

```
{ 
  start: '2017-08-22T13:00:00.000Z',
  end: '2017-08-22T14:00:00.000Z',
  'exceptions/browser': { sum: 1 } 
}
{ 
  start: '2017-08-23T14:00:00.000Z',
  end: '2017-08-23T15:00:00.000Z',
  'exceptions/browser': { sum: 0 } 
}
{ 
  start: '2017-08-23T15:00:00.000Z',
  end: '2017-08-23T16:00:00.000Z',
  'exceptions/browser': { sum: 0 } 
}
{ 
  start: '2017-08-23T16:00:00.000Z',
  end: '2017-08-23T17:00:00.000Z',
  'exceptions/browser': { sum: 1 } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would require using the query API, and formalize your query using [Analytics Query Language](https://docs.loganalytics.io/index).
The query I'm running to get the same data as you wanted is:

```
exceptions
| where timestamp >= ago(24h)
| where client_Type=="Browser"
| make-series count() default=0 on timestamp in range(ago(24h), now(), 1h)
| mvexpand count_ to typeof(long), timestamp to typeof(datetime)
```

Few things to note:

- I filtered with `client_Type=="Browser"` to match the `exceptions/browser` query
- In order to "fill in the blanks" you have to use `make-series` and not `summarize`
- Final URL for query is: `https://api.applicationinsights.io/beta/apps/DEMO_APP/query?query=exceptions%7C%20where%20timestamp%20%3E%3D%20ago(24h)%7C%20where%20client_Type%3D%3D%22Browser%22%7C%20make-series%20count()%20default%3D0%20on%20timestamp%20in%20range(ago(24h)%2C%20now()%2C%201h)%7C%20mvexpand%20count_%20to%20typeof(long)%2C%20timestamp%20to%20typeof(datetime)`

Comment: While this works, if there has been no data recorded in the last 24hours, nothing comes back and causes an undefined error. Is it possible to make it always return data even if none has been recorded in the last 24 hours?

Answer (score 0):

You're using the metric portion of the API, use the query portion.

The query will still return Json but the in odata standard.  Which means paging will need to be involved.

The query calls will allow you to return all columns and all rows.

Comment: How do i translate the metric into a query? Is there somewhere i can learn about app insight querys?

Comment: @CallumBrankin I use application insights to get most of my queries started. At the top of all the charts and graphs in the upper right hand corner is a weird icon that looks like a page of boxes.  If you click that it will take you to the query that was used to create that chart, all you have to do from there is practically copy and paste (removing the charting statement at the bottom of the query)